# HR Tag Shows Up, But No Styling Possible

Tags: html, css

I am using the following HTML code:

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 3px double #333;
  color: #333;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5px;
}

hr:after {
  background: #fff;
  content: "§";
  padding: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hr.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>§1: The first rule of Fight Club is: You do not talk about Fight Club.
  </p>
  <hr>
  <p>§2: The second rule of Fight Club is: Always bring cupcakes.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

What should be happening is that TWO horizontal rules should appear between the two sentences, with an curly shape in the middle.

What is happening is that only a regular single horizontal rule appears.

What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) clear your cache (2) verify the CSS file path

Comment: control f5 will do a fresh load instead of cache.

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet shows your favoured outcome, perhaps in your working environment you have a cached version of your styles?

This in essence means that your browser is loading an older version of your code, you will need to force it to load the newer version, to do this in Google Chrome, open up your developer tools using `right click > inspect` and then hold down your mouse button on the refresh button until a dropdown appears.

When it does, try to select the option `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`